# Cannot reference Imageview object of custom layout in another activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I am trying to referee an imageview object which is part of listview (custom layout),int another Activity to set image icon based on user selection of Event type.But I am not able to achieve this , the icon not gets changed

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <!-- THUMBAIL IMAGE -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="85dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:shadowColor="#585858"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="20"
            android:src="@drawable/karthik" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Facebook Friend"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!-- ARROW IMAGE -->


    <!-- NAME -->
    <!-- CONTACT NUMBER -->


    <!-- BIRTHDATE -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_row"
        android:text="KARTHIK.KOLANJI"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_zodiac"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
        android:text="Sagittarius"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_turns"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_image_arrow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_image_arrow"
        android:text="24"
        android:textColor="#990000"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
        android:text="Next birthday on : "
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="Wednesday"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_name"
        android:text="9594080469"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15dip" 
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_image_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sub_title_category"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
        android:text="turns"
        android:textColor="#996600"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_days_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="36"
        android:textColor="#990000"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_width="15dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_row"
        android:contentDescription="Zodiac icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:shadowColor="#8B4513"
        android:shadowDx="0.0"
        android:shadowDy="0.0"
        android:shadowRadius="20" 
        android:src="@drawable/rings_icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:text="(Anniversary)"
        android:textColor="#787878"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
        android:text="Zodiac :  "
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="7th, April 1990"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtview_turns"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:text=" days left"
        android:textColor="#996600"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="Zodiac icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:shadowColor="#8B4513"
        android:shadowDx="0.0"
        android:shadowDy="0.0"
        android:shadowRadius="20" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

ContactInfoMoreOption.java

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v=LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
final ImageView imgView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
switch(id){
case 2:  // Change event type alert dialog  
                try{                    
                    spnView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.choose_type)));
                    alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Change event type");
                    alertBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.change_event_type);             
                    alertBuilder.setView(spnView);
                    alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @SuppressWarnings("null")
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if (spnView.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("User defined")) {
                                showDialog(USER_DEFINED_EVENT_NAME);
                            }
                            else{
                                ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                                values.put(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_TYPE, spnView.getSelectedItem().toString());                      
                                int count=getContentResolver().update(BirthdayProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, BirthdayProvider.NUMBER+"='"+SearchListActivity.longClickValue+"'", null);
                                if (count==1) {
                                    String iconType = null;
                                    if (spnView.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Birthday")) {
                                        iconType="app_icon.png";
                                    }
                                    else if (spnView.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Anniversary")){
                                        iconType="rings_icon.png";
                                    }
                                    InputStream is = null;

                                        try {
                                            is = getResources().getAssets().open("rings_icon.png");
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        Log.v("is......", is.toString());

                                    Bitmap bit =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
                                    Log.v("bit......", bit.toString());
                                    imgView.setImageBitmap(bit);

                                    imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                                    finish();
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                 else{
                                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updation Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 }
                            }                       
                        }
                    });     
                    alertDialog=alertBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                    return alertDialog;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which image view is the one giving you problems?

Comment: android:id="@+id/ImageView02" is the one

Comment: Where are you trying to reference it in code?

Comment: edited ...... inside onCreateDialog

Comment: please clear this up ..basically you have a listview , on some action(with the listview item i suppose) you open the dialog and in Ok button press you want the listview item (because of which dialog was open) image to change .. Is my explanation correct ?

Comment: on listview longclick I open a dialog themed activity containing option EdtContact. On click of this option opens another dialog themed activity containing Change Event Type

Comment: in the second dialog themed activity you change the type and on closing the dialog you want the listiview Image to change new Image based on the new type selected ?

Comment: @baboo -- in short .. ListviewActivity ----> Dialog Themed Activity ---->Dialog Themed Activity

Comment: @baboo -- absolutely yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing/changing the imageview of listview layout directly from second Dialog activity, you need to access the adapter of the listview based on which you populate the listview items, So basically send the selected item INDEX to the dialog activities, inside the dialog activities use adapter.getItem(index) and change the item (that is change Event Type),  and  also do call adapter.notifydatasetchanged for changes to occur in listview... 
Basically access the adapter item in dialogs  and modify that item

Answer (score 0):

Two things. Make sure you have not imported the Android R file by mistake. Also clean your project and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I checked these 2 things... still not working.. if done this code directly on the activity that uses this custom layout , then it works

Comment: What class is your create dialog in?